# Cannot update user information using Google PHP API Client library

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I am trying to update user phone numbers on Google Apps Directory. Currently I have the API able to retrieve information on user's but when I try to set their phone numbers it just silently fails. The values do not update in the directory. It is possible I may be just missing a method that actually sends the data but I have been unable to find such a method.

My current scopes are:

```
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit');
```

My attempts at saving phone numbers have been varied. I have tried:

```
$work_phone = new \Google_Service_Directory_UserPhone();
        $work_phone->setType('work');
        $work_phone->setValue($work_number);
$google_user->setPhones(array($work_phone));
```

And

```
$google_user->setPhones(array(array(
          "type"=>"work",
          "value"=>$work_number
        )));
```

As well as a variety of values for the type array structures. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the phone number in the directory, you need to send the information back to Google. With your code:

```
$google_user->setPhones(array($work_phone));
```

You are setting the object's phones array correctly. You still need to update that user however. You were correct when you said:

> I may be just missing a method that actually sends the data

You would need to do something like this:

```
$work_phone = new \Google_Service_Directory_UserPhone();
        $work_phone->setType('work');
        $work_phone->setValue($work_number);
$google_user->setPhones(array($work_phone));

$serviceDirectory = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$serviceDirectory->users->update($google_user);
```

Relevent API documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update